# SAS3 HBA / Backplane Issue

Tags: ssd, sas, supermicro, hba

I have the Supermicro BPN-SAS3-743A backplane hooked up to a AOC-S3008L-L8i RAID card in IT mode using a regular mini SAS SFF-8643 to SFF-8643 cable bought from Amazon. When I'm in the HBA bios, the topology shows no drives even though there are 4 SSD drives connected. If I attach the drives directly using a breakout cable, the drives are detected but not when connected to the backplane. The backplane's lights flash for a split second when the system is powered on initially and the lights are green in the filed bays and red in the empty ones. Could there be an incompatibility with the cable and backplane? Any other ideas to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drives were not fully inserted due to the SSDs being mounted upside down in the drive tray. The tray went in but the drives didn't actually connect to the physical interface.